# Autoload helper classes in tests/src/ for phpunit in contrib module

Tags: 9, testing

I am working on a contrib module with phpunit tests.

Currently there is no composer.json or phpunit.xml or installation routine in the module itself, instead one has to run the functional and browser tests from a custom drupal site, where the module is installed in web/modules/contrib/*. So far this works.

Now I want to use helper classes in `tests/src/Helper/`, in namespace `"Drupal\\Tests\\$modulename\\Helper\\"` and possibly elsewhere.

However, I noticed that `drupal_phpunit_get_extension_namespaces()` only registers some select namespaces within `"Drupal\\Tests\\$modulename\\"`, instead of the entire namespace.

My questions:

- Why does Drupal phpunit integration behave this way, instead of registering the entire `tests/src/` namespace directory?
- What is a good way to register the entire `tests/src/` directory in the class loader? I still want to be able to run the tests from Drupal installation outside the module itself.

---

EDIT: New issue on drupal.org: [#3258817: Why don't we register all of /tests/src/ for class loading?](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3258817)

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a dirty workaround here, that can be easily copied without adjusting any code.

There might be better solutions, I am open for other answers!

Also, I won't promise 100% that this works in all circumstances. Perhaps opcache can bring nasty surprises?

Create the following file in `"tests/src/$modulename/Traits/AutoloadHelperTrait.php"`.
Replace `<MODULENAME>` with the real module name.

```php
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Registers the entire 'tests/src/' directory in the class loader.
 *
 * By default, Drupal phpunit integration registers only _some_ namespace
 * directories within 'tests/src/' in the class loader. One of them is
 * '/Traits/'. 
 * This workaround registers the top-level namespace.
 *
 * The code is written in a way that can easily be copied to other modules:
 * - It is independent of the module name.
 * - It is independent of where the module is placed in the filesystem.
 *
 * See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/autoload-helper-classes-in-tests-src-for-phpunit-in-contrib-module
 *
 * @see \drupal_phpunit_populate_class_loader()
 * @see \drupal_phpunit_get_extension_namespaces()
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\Tests\<MODULENAME>\Traits;

use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

\call_user_func(static function (): void {
  // The Composer ClassLoader class is always present in the same location
  // within the vendor directory. From there we can work our way to the
  // autoload.php to get the real class loader. 
  $rc = new \ReflectionClass(ClassLoader::class);
  /** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $classLoader */
  $classLoader = require dirname($rc->getFileName(), 2) . '/autoload.php';
  // Determine the namespace and directory from magic constants.
  // This allows the code to be copied elsewhere.
  $level = \substr_count(__NAMESPACE__, '\\');
  $dir = dirname(__DIR__, $level - 2);
  // The namespace always starts with 'Drupal\Tests\', independent of the
  // module name.
  $nspos = \strpos(__NAMESPACE__, '\\', 13);
  $namespace = \substr(__NAMESPACE__, 0, $nspos + 1);
  $classLoader->addPsr4($namespace, $dir);
});

/**
 * Include this trait to register the entire tests/src/ for class loading.
 */
trait AutoloadHelperTrait {}
```

Now include the trait in any test class that needs this autoloading enabled. Or include it from a test base class.